# Can we integrate third party service in Siri without installing app?

Tags: ios, iphone, siri, sirikit

One of my healthcare related service, I want to integrate third party service in Siri...

Is it possible to add this feature without installing the third party app...

Google Assistant in Android provides this feature without installing that app...

Comment: You must install an app to support Siri Intents.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any another way to do this or need to implement with app..?

Comment: You need to install an app.  Apple's architecture is very different to Google and Amazon. A lot of Siri processing happens on the iOS device in order to improve user privacy

Answer (score 0):

From the official [Siri Intents documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension):

> Interactions with SiriKit occur through your Intents app extension, **which you deliver inside your iOS or watchOS app bundle.**